# Coherence cache members time out and are removed from the cluster

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle-coherence

Coherence cache members time out and are removed from the cluster in a Spring Hibernate Tomcat application. As a result data is not in sync and all the cache members are not updated at the same time. 
This application has been running in PROD and the only change we did recently was upgrading Tomcat.
This is a production issue. ANy suggestions would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, cache members are removed when they time-out or put another way, they stop responding to the rest of the cluster.

The most likely reason for this to happen is that a stop-the-world garbage collection is occurring and hence the heartbeats that keep a member in a cluster are not being sent.

In the short term you'll need to review the garbage collection logs (hope you've got those configured) and ultimately profile/tune your application to ensure the memory use and garbage collection are efficient.

Longer term, it's a bad idea to have processes not purely related to the cluster joining the cluster, especially if they are storage enabled.  You should use Extend TCP to allow these other processes to gain access to the cache instead.

The reason for this is that, using your situation as an example, Tomcat has all sorts of resource requirements that ultimately introduce a wider set of memory/garbage collection demands on the JVM than just being a cluster member.  As such tuning the JVM for the wider demands will introduce more compromise and ultimate make it harder to run a JVM where Memory/GC is optimised to keep the cluster stable.